# Angular dealing with incorrect cached data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

Okay this might be a long post but please do not click away you may know a simple answer.

**The case:**

Lets say you have build an angular app where people log into the system do some operations and then might log out again. The application will collect data from an API using a factory and service and in order to make the `application` load even faster you save these data in variables like such:

```
app.factory("divisionService", function (api, $http, $q) {
var division = {};
var divisionArray = [];
var mergedUserList = [];
return {
    getList: function () {
        var d = $q.defer();
        if (divisionArray <= 0) {
            $http.get(api.getUrl('divisionWithUsers', null))
                .success(function (response) {
                    divisionArray = response;
                    d.resolve(divisionArray);
                });

        }
        if (divisionArray.length > 0) {
            d.resolve(divisionArray);
        }
        return d.promise;
    },
```

This will make sure that if the user attempts to use a controller that uses the `divisionService` then that user will instantly get the data if it is already fetched.

**The issue:**

Now the user log's out and another user logs in (without refreshing / reloading ) the page. Once the controller calls this factory it already thinks that it has the correct list meaning that return would be the same as the previous user however this data might be incorrect!

Since all angular services are `singletons` the service will not be destoryed upon logout even though it should.

**The obvious answer**

An answer to this question might be: "Well then don't store the data in a variable" and since this will work enormous amount of data might make content of the page load slowly.

So my question is what do you do in the above situation? do you really have to deal with loading the data every time it is request or does `angular` provide a smart way to solve this problem?

Comment: is the user information, like the username, stored in this data you're getting?

Comment: @aw04 no. the data stored in this example is a list of buildings that belong to the individuel user

Comment: so how do you know they belong to that individual user?

Comment: @aw04 my api accepts a token this token contains the user_id that my DBM will use to search the correct data

Comment: got it, i don't know if this works in your case but my first thought is to cache that userid or token as well and compare it to see if it's changed before deciding whether to refresh the data

Comment: @aw04 that could work yes. But angular does not provide a way to do this automaticly? like a function you can call to clear ?

Comment: i don't know to be honest, looks like @Jossef Harush has posted an answer along those lines that's probably worth checking out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Create a `clear()` function

Add a `clear()` function to your `divisionService` factory which will be responsible to empty the cached data structures (arrays, objects, ...)

```
app.factory("divisionService", function () {
    var division = {};
    var divisionArray = [];
    var mergedUserList = [];
    return {
        clear: function(){
            // Clear the cached data

            for (var key in division)
            {
                delete division[key];
            }

            divisionArray.length = 0;

            // ...
        },
        getList: ...
    }
});
```

And call this function from **when you logout**

```
function logout(){
    divisionService.clear();
}
```

## Refresh the application

You can also refresh the entire application when you logout if you don't want to deal with clearing the cached data (e.g. calling `divisionService.clear()`)

```
function logout(){
    $window.location.reload();
}
```

this will cause the entire application to be reloaded, and all of the temporary (variable based) cached data will be cleared

Comment: this is a nice approach, cleaner than my answer i think

Answer (score 1):

Marc,

My first thought is just run
 divisionArray = [];

On logout. Let me know if that works.  If not,  I'll look into it further.

Comment: This could solve the problem however i would have to do this for each of the services im using and it seems rather redundant?

Answer (score 1):

You can cache the user information as well and compare it to see if the user has changed before deciding to refresh the data.